# Storing html components in database

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to store html components of my website in the database in order to let the user choose from a variety of components each time

for example :

one page styled html page with a navbar and about section that could be changed and other stuff , it's layout could contain the following :

```
    <div id="nav-holder">
      <!-- Nav html goes here -->
    </div>

    <div id="about-holder">
      <!-- about section html goes here -->
    </div>

    <!-- other html stuff -->
```

My db now is structured to hold the template with it's possible components for each section , and is storing a 'text' in it's html column , and I am adding all my styling and scripting to one sheet and js file that is loaded for the whole layout.

Is there any best practice to store and render those components in my db ?

#### Edit :

My main purpose is to create a website generator with some customization , providing a set of templates that the user chooses and within one template he can customize his template by choosing different components (navs,about sections , ... )

Also I will grab the data from some place and fill it into those templates **The user will not be able to modify the data here , it's ready already** so there is no need to give the user the ability to modify the data that would be filled in the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any best practice to store and render those components in my
>   db ?

Yes, don't! For several reasons, the primary one being that you use your database to persistently store variables related to models. Not html. The place for your html is in your views, the place to make choices as to which html to show is in your controllers.

Other reasons include that reading your html from a database will slow down your apps responsiveness and Rails tends to make text from a database html safe, meaning it will not automatically behave as html. This is a security precaution as a very common attack is to insert 'bad' code into your database which then gets run when you recover it and supply it to an unsuspecting user.

Use partials. Reference section 3.4 of [this Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Save the users choices of components in the database. If he chooses navbar_23, you store that 9 character string in the database and on request, your template serves him the partial named _navbar_23.html.erb from your views folder.

For example, in your views folder, create a subfolder views/navbars, inside that place your variants of navbars. Partials start with an underscore and end with .html.erb

In your model, store the users choice of navbar in say user.navbar. Just the name, not the starting underscore or .html.erb

In your template;

```
render partial: "views/navbars/" + user.navbar
```

Rails will automagically add the underscore and .html.erb when it looks for the file.

Comment: I know but let's say that I want to give the user the ability to choose from many navbars for the website , the only idea I got to store the navs in my db and query them , is there another (idea ,technology,tool, ... ) that I should search for ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanElkady you could use an editable markup like http://liquidmarkup.org/

Comment: @HassaninAhmed this would help If I need to change the text-nodes in my tags    

, However I want to give the user the ability to change the whole component (Another design with another classes and tags)

Comment: Look up partials, these are Rails view components you can render within another view component. Navbars, headers and footers are classic use cases for partials. You don't need other fancy tricks :-)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanElkady I think you could still use Liquid. Take a look at this https://github.com/akitaonrails/dynamic_liquid_templates I think it'll help. Good luck.

Comment: I think all of these ideas are good and I'll start searching about it , however I think it's still not getting my main purpose 

I updated the question to clarify what I want to do .. if it is doable with this ideas then just tell me to check this approach :)) thanks a lot

Comment: The key is that it is you that is creating the components. What you need to save is the users choices of components in the database, not the html. If he chooses navbar_23, you store that 9 character string in the database and on request, your template serves him the partial named _navbar_23.erb.html from your views folder.

Comment: @MattStevens That's cool , then if I have for example 10 templates and I have some components for them I just store the components in partials and manage the relations in the db , however I just point to the template and the partial in the db instead of writing html there ... If yes please update ur answer because the latest comment is the answer ;)

Adding a very simple folder structure will be very helpful also ... thank you in advance :))